# Angular Material - Directly passing an object to a FormControl

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've came across an issue in Angular Material where you are not able to pre set the `<mat-select>` value if you *directly pass an object* to a **FormControl**.

**app.component.html**

```
<!-- NOTE: The only difference is in [formControl] value -->

<!-- This example works well because I'm using 'toppings' form control -->
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="toppings">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping.name}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<!-- This is where it fails, no value is preselected -->
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Toppings 2</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="toppings2">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping.name}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
  toppingList: any[] = [
    {id: 42, name: "Item3123"},
    {id: 45, name: "Item444"},
    {id: 426, name: "Iteml"},
  ]
  toppings = new FormControl(this.toppingList[0]);
  toppings2 = new FormControl({id: 42, name: "Item3123"});
```

As you can see the difference between toppings and toppings2 is the way I pass the object. In the end, the object is exactly the same. I tried doing the same thing without using Angular Material (using normal `<select>`) and it works great.

[StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gubnkx)

Does anyone have an explanation for such a behaviour?

Comment: The object is not exactly the same. In the first case, it's one of the options. In the second case, it's not: it's a different object, which happens to have the equal properties, but which is not === to any of the options.

Comment: please refer to this post which describes in detail the point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40979640/setting-selected-option-of-select-control-in-an-angular-2-model-driven-form

Comment: This does not solve the problem I mentioned. The approach WORKS if I bind the form control to normal <select> instead of <mat-select>. Please check the stackblitz

Comment: But it doesn't work. It also "works" if you do `toppings2 = new FormControl({});` The normal select just selects the first option if you pass it any kind of object.

Answer (score 3):

The explanation can be found in the first comment on your question by JB Nizet - they are not the same object (they merely have the same id and name) so an ordinary comparison such as `==` or `===` fails. The [default compare function in MatSelect](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/select/select.ts) which is used to determine whether or not a list item is selected is:

```
private _compareWith = (o1: any, o2: any) => o1 === o2;
```

The solution is to use the `compareWith` feature to substitute your own compare function:

```
<mat-select [formControl]="toppings2" [compareWith]="compareToppings">

compareToppings(t1, t2) {
  return t1.id === t2.id;
}
```

Further reading:
http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/object-equality-in-javascript.html